# where does debrelease put the package?

Tags: unix, debian

I use debrealse command to setup my package. But I cannot find it on disk. Where can I find it?

Comment: You should probably post this on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

debrelease is in devscripts, if that is what you are asking.

```
$ dpkg -S debrelease
devscripts: /usr/bin/debrelease
devscripts: /usr/share/man/fr/man1/cvs-debrelease.1.gz
devscripts: /usr/share/man/man1/cvs-debrelease.1.gz
devscripts: /usr/share/man/fr/man1/debrelease.1.gz
devscripts: /usr/share/man/man1/debrelease.1.gz
devscripts: /usr/bin/cvs-debrelease
```